# How do i get 2 arguments from the same message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have tried splicing the message but it doesnt work as intended, only partially. Heres my code

```js
module.exports = {
name: 'sandwich',
execute(message, args) {
      let ingredient1 = args.slice(1).join(" ");
      let ingredient2 = args.slice(2).join(" ");

      message.channel.send(`Making a sandwich with ${ingredient1},${ingredient2}.`)

}
```

but the bot sends "Making a sandwich with bacon cheese, cheese"

What i want to do is:

user inputs `&sandwich bacon cheese`

bot sends "Making a sandwich with bacon, cheese"

Comment: split user input string

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
name: 'sandwich',
execute(message, args) {
      let ingredients = args.join(", ");

      message.channel.send(`Making a sandwich with ${args[0]},${args[1]}.`)
      message.channel.send(`Making a sandwich with ${ingredients}.`)
}
```

also you can send object in JSON

```
execute(message, args) {
          let ingredients = args.join(", ");
          let messageToSend = {
             ingredients: args,
             sentence: `Making a sandwich with ${ingredients}.`
          }
   
          message.channel.send(JSON.stringify(messageToSend));
    }
```

to decode on the other side, do JSON.parse(message) to retrive the object

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'sandwich',
    execute(message, args) {
        const ingredients = args.join(" ");
        const [ingredient1, ingredient2] = ingredients.split(",", 2);
        message.channel.send(`Making a sandwich with ${ingredient1},${ingredient2}.`);
}
```